# How do I create varied colors for buttons in Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm using this code to create a series of buttons in Java GUI, exactly 20 buttons, that has 20 different colors. Somehow, however, I couldn't, and if I use this code, I would end up coloring all 20 buttons in one, same color. How do I color them all with different colors in each buttons? Thank you in advance. Note that from the code, I do not use listed array.

```
        setTitle("My Frame");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5));

        int R = (int) (Math.random()*256);
        int G = (int) (Math.random()*256);
        int B = (int) (Math.random()*256);
        Color color = new Color(R, G, B);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            setBackground(color);
            add(button);
        }
        setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `R`, `G`, `B`, and subsequently `color` are assigned a random value *once*, before the loop `for` starts. Then, throughout the loop, they retain the same values, so you end up with the same color for all of your buttons.

Try creating a new `Color` value in each iteration of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int R = (int) (Math.random()*256);
    int G = (int) (Math.random()*256);
    int B = (int) (Math.random()*256);
    Color color = new Color(R, G, B);

    JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
    setBackground(color);
    add(button);
}
```

Now each iteration of the loop gets its own different random value for `R`, `G`, `B` (and `color`).

Comment: Thank you, it worked right away! I feel dumb now, making a rookie mistake like that...

Answer (score 0):

```
        setTitle("My Frame");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5));

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int R = (int) (Math.random()*256);
            int G = (int) (Math.random()*256);
            int B = (int) (Math.random()*256);
            Color color = new Color(R, G, B);
            JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            setBackground(color);
            add(button);
        }
        setVisible(true);
```